# How to change a forms Menu

Tags: delphi, menu, delphi-xe4

I have an app originally written using Delphi 2005.

It has a page control and depending on which tab is selected it presents a different Menu.

```
case PageControl.ActivePageIndex of
  0: begin
    Menu := HeaderMenu;
  end;
  1: begin
    Menu := DetailMenu;
  end;
end;
```

In XE this does not work and the menu does not change. How can I replace the forms Menu with another when a new tab is selected?

The Following Shows what I am trying to do. Unfortunately it works as expected. M app has over 100 forms so I can't post it all

**Main Form**

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    MainMenu2: TMainMenu;
    OpenSecondWindow1: TMenuItem;
    Dummy1: TMenuItem;
    SwitchMenus1: TMenuItem;
    Dummy2: TMenuItem;
    SwitchMenus2: TMenuItem;
    OpenSecondWindow2: TMenuItem;
    procedure SwitchMenus2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OpenSecondWindow1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit6;

procedure TForm5.OpenSecondWindow1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form6.Show();
end;

procedure TForm5.SwitchMenus2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Menu = MainMenu1 then
    Menu := MainMenu2
  else
    Menu := MainMenu1;
end;

end.
```

The Second Form

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    MainMenu2: TMainMenu;
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    Menu11: TMenuItem;
    File1: TMenuItem;
    insert1: TMenuItem;
    save1: TMenuItem;
    Menu21: TMenuItem;
    Stuff1: TMenuItem;
    Save2: TMenuItem;
    Donoting1: TMenuItem;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet3: TTabSheet;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure PageControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm6.PageControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case PageControl1.TabIndex of
    0: Menu := MainMenu1;
    1: Menu := MainMenu2;
    2: Menu := nil;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: What is the context of the code in the question. Where does it live?

Comment: It lives as a form that is opened from the mainform of my application.

Comment: Now this is interesting. I put breakpoints on the Menu := statements and ran in debug mode. And the Menus changed properly. When I removed the breakpoints the no longer updated.

Comment: I still have no idea what the context of this code is. It lives in a procedure. When does that procedure run? Can't we have an SSCCE? If you provided one we'd have an answer for you.

Comment: Even more information. It seems to not that the debugger is doing anything other than switching me to XE4. If I run without the debugger and Alt Tab to switch to another program and back the menus repaint themselves. I have tried adding self.Invalidate and self.Repaint to the code to no avail.

Comment: Why won't you post an SSCCE?

Comment: Hi David. I am working on a SSCCE but where do I put it?

Comment: This is a wiki site. The question can be edited. When you are ready, edit the question and add the sscce.

Comment: Hi David. No luck with a SSCCE. When I drop the application down to two forms it all works exactly as expected.

Comment: What can I tell you. If you cannot supply code that illustrates the issue then there's little we can do.

Answer (score 2):

Tested this and it works:

```
procedure TfmMain.PageControlChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case PageControl.ActivePageIndex of
    0: Menu := MainMenu1;
    else Menu := MainMenu2;
  end;
end;
```

Note: On placing the first MainMenu on the form, the form property "Menu" is set to MainMenu1.

Tested in XE3

Comment: This works because it is the main form. If it is on a form created by the main form then it does not.

Comment: @farley - Why? I see no problem switching menus in a secondary form.

Comment: That is the problem. This app was runnng fine before XE4. If I scale it down the code works fine. But in my app with ove 100 forms it does ot update the menu until the application loses focus and then it regains it. (Clicking the mouse on another app for example)